# Terra::extract delivers unexpected values when extracting table from raster using polygons

Tags: r, extract, terra

I have a categorical raster and a polygon vector layer. I want to get a table with the area of each class from the raster layer that is covered by polygons.

I tried the following:

```
extr <- terra::extract(
    raster, polygons, fun = table, exact = TRUE, weights = FALSE
)

areas <- terra::expanse(polygons, unit = "ha")

tble <- extr
for (c in seq(2, ncol(extr))) {
    tble[, c] <- extr[, c] * polygon_areas
}

sums <- colSums(tble, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, the areas covered by polygons are larger than the areas per class when I run

```
terra::expanse(terra::as.polygons(raster), unit = "ha")
```

When I checked the polygons, they were non-overlapping.

Am I using `extract` in the wrong way here?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured `terra::extract` does not return the fraction of polygon area covered (though the number of rows in the output table equals the number of polygons within the vector layer), but the values are given as a fraction of a raster grid cell. Thus, I need to multiply with the raster cell area.